# How can I add a spreadsheet to the question I want to ask?

Tags: feature-request

I wanted some help understanding the home loan amortization chart I got from the bank. However, Since we cannot add spreadsheets to teh question, I dont know how I can smartly share that data in the question. Since this is a "Finance" QA Forum, maybe we should have a document upload section ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a link to a Google Doc or other online, share-able, office type program?  You could post the document to a Dropbox account (or similar) for sharing as well.

I know some of those services are not available universally, but something like that?

Comment: Once you delete the document from Google Docs or online storage the question becomes worthless.

Answer (score 7):

I'd be uncomfortable with that since file uploads tend to be abused on the internet, and even in legitimate posts we run the risk of people unintentionally exposing personal information.

Why don't you screen shot the relevant parts of the document and embed the image?

Comment: +1 I came here to make the screenshot suggestion.

Comment: Screenshot is best. A few lines of the amortization are enough to ask the question clearly.